# Is an apostrophe required in "a good ten minutes away"

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

I think if I wrote "a good ten minutes' walk away" then an apostrophe is required as shown.

If I write "a good ten minutes away", where 'walk' is implied from the context, is it still required?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it is *forbidden* to use an apostrophe in "a good ten minutes away".

Comparison with the situation in the singular may make this clear: *"an hour's away" seems clearly unacceptable to me, whereas "an hour away" is acceptable. Also, when the word *away* is used with the word *foot,* which takes an irregular plural, we say things like "five feet away" and not *"five feet's away".

I agree with with what Michael Harvey says about the apostrophe only being used with duration words when a noun follows (as in *five days' work*). *Away* is not a noun.

I'm not sure whether you meant to suggest this, but I don't think "a good ten minutes away" contains any kind of implicit noun after the word "minutes". Rather, "ten minutes" seems to be used here as a measurement of distance. Using the word "minutes" to refer to distance is semantically indirect, but  as far as I can tell, "ten minutes" takes the exact same *syntactic* role here as a phrase that refers to distance more literally, such as "two miles" or "twenty meters".

Answer (score 2):

No apostrophe for the second example, where the time (duration) is not linked to a noun (walk, wait, etc).

> We can use an apostrophe + s to show duration. When the time noun is
>   plural, the apostrophe comes after the s:
>
> For me, writing an essay involves at least an hour’s work.
>
> It was just **ten minutes’ walk** from my house to my office. (the walk
>   from my house to my office takes just ten minutes)

[Apostrophe (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/apostrophe)

Answer (score 0):

> "a good ten minutes' walk away"

No apostrophe is required if the sentence is as follows:

> It was a ('good' in the sense of ample) ten **minute** walk from my house to my office.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question about how to write "a good ten minutes away".